# Splitting strings and joining the duplicates

Tags: php, string, duplicates

I'm trying to create a select box drop down with a twist,

Basically this is an Ajax form that when an item is selected from the list it'll add it into a text field. However I also want to add a few extra selections in here.

the string I'm getting is made up of *`COMPANY`*`_`*`SITE`*`_`*`DEPARTMENT`* and for example `SDGCC_NEWTOWN_INBOUND`.

Using PHP I wish to take every item from the database in the logintags table which could contain multiple *`COMPANY`*`_` so anything that states `SDGCC` I want the drop down box to have the special selection for adding *all* `SDGCC` sites if that makes sense? I've tried it but I get duplicates if there is more than one row that contains the `SDGCC` tag.

duplicates :

> `SDGCC_NEWTOWN_INBOUND`
>   `SDGCC_NEWTOWN_QH`
>   `SDGCC_BOLTON_QH`
>   `ARISE_HOME_ORDERS`
>   `ARISE_HOME_ENQUIRIES`

etc...

So basically it'd have an option to select all SDGCC sites but because that database could change at any point we only need the first part of the string (ie the SDGCC, ARISE) sections to show up (once) in the select box.

I'm currently trying suggested query from below

> SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING( tag, 0, LOCATE('_',  tag ) ) 
>   FROM  `dept_logintags` 
>   LIMIT 0 , 30

However this returns no rows

Comment: You may what to rephrase you question, I really don't understand what you want. What is a "SDGCC" or "logintags"? Could you use more general valid terms? And maybe provide an example...

Comment: if you read, SDGCC is part of a string that is what i want to be split.

Comment: Do you want to have a CROSS JOIN in the end on all three values?

Comment: Can you give an example of the item that is selected from the DropDown?

Comment: Can you give an example of the Duplicates?

Comment: added example of the duplicates hope this helps your understanding

Comment: Based on your example list, my first select example will return unique values from the DB.

Comment: and that one SELECT distinct SUBSTRING(logintags, 0, CHARINDEX(logintags, '_')) FROM TableName gives a sql error as stated in the below comment

Comment: why did you hardcode 'SDGCC_NEWTOWN_INBOUND'? I've added additional code in my answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Don't reinvent the wheel

Basically what you want is a distinct on the `COMPANY_` part of your logintags.

Why don't you read data from your DB as `DISTINCT`? You can easily make a `DISTINCT` on the first part of the string value by using an expression column in your query that strips out the first part. So you wouldn't need any string manipulation on the middle tier at all?

**Example for Microsoft SQL**

```
// first part
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(tag, 0, CHARINDEX(tag, '_')) FROM dept_logintags
// second part
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(tag, CHARINDEX(tag, '_') + 1, LEN(tag)), 0, CHARINDEX(tag, '_')) from dept_logintagss
// last part
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(tag, CHARINDEX(tag, '_') + 1, LEN(tag)), CHARINDEX(tag, '_') + 1, LEN(tag)) from dept_logintags
```

Because in the end you would like to do the same thing in PHP.

**Example for MySQL**

In MySQL you can even use SUBSTRING_INDEX function to simplify selects even further

```
// first part
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(tag, '_', 1) FROM dept_logintags
// second part
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tag, '_', 2), '_', -1) from dept_logintags
// last part
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(tag, '_', -1) FROM dept_logintags
```

Comment: would the added code be enough? If you need to return more columns, than do a GROUP BY the expression column

Comment: ok, so how does the database know what table your getting that from, because i just get no field logintags in fieldlist

Comment: I omittedt table name because the expression is more important. So I added it now. The thing is that you get the point.

Comment: #1305 - FUNCTION sdg_comms.CHARINDEX does not exist

Comment: In MySQL LOCATE would be the right function but be careful with parameters because the first two must be switched.

Comment: this is great the SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX works fine, how would we modify this to get the second part of the string, so having the option to filter by site... eg getting NEWTOWN from the tags

Comment: just use nested function like: SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tag, '_', 2), '_', -1)